# What's the Rails Way to get the Model Class from the Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can do this in the controller to get the model class:

```
self.class.name.gsub("Controller", "").singularize.constantize
```

But is there a built in method for this in the controller?

Something like `self.model_class`?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `@model_obj.class.constantize` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActionPack` and `ActiveRecord` are separate modules, so there's no built-in support for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
params[:controller].classify.constantize
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `params[:controller].classify.constantize`?

Comment: I don't think this does what viatropos is asking. He wants the name of the *model* from inside a controller, and this gives the controller. Controllers do not have inherent connections to models, so I believe Sam's answer is the correct one.

Comment: I assumed that he wanted User inside UsersController. Otherwise, as you and Sam say, it's impossible

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
controller_name.classify
```

Comment: This cuts off namespaces

Comment: These are equivalent:

Comment: Intended full comment: controller_name.classify() is equivalent to self.class.name.gsub("Controller", "").singularize(). It seems to me this need to relate the model to the controller arises quite often, for instance, if you have an ORM hierarchy. It's wasteful to copy the same code into every subclass (e.g. for new()) and just change the model name.